# Jenkins Master/Slave Network I/O

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, master-slave

We are using Jenkins on a single machine - and as the builds were getting slow - I looked around for options (installing it on newer hardware / adding slaves). As many forums were suggesting the master/slave architecture for scalability - I decided to go that way.

Our code repository is Mercurial. And here's the problem - every time I build a project - the existing repository on the slave is erased and the project files are copied to it again - thereby losing the incremental network I/O. Transferring files over the network is wiping out all the benefits of faster compilation! Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The I/O here is not related to the Master-Slave configuration,
but to the way the Slave (or Master) interacts with the Source-Control system.

Are you working with the **[Mercurial Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin)** ?
I am not familiar with Mercurial, but the documentation there mentions polling for source-code changes
and the UI looks quite comprehensive.

Worst case you can write your own script that will check-out all modified files to a shared location
(don't use the default location, which is in the Workspace of your job).

Good luck!